# Configuring iptables: blocked out on SSH

Tags: linux, centos, ssh, iptables

I am trying to configure a testserver based on CentOS 6.4.
I have changed the default SSH port to another port, 56988. Now I am trying to create a set of rules in order to:

- Allow connections on 56988 with a maximum (to prevent bruteforce)
- Accept incoming and outgoing connections on 80 and 443, limited to prevent DOS attacks
- Block everything else

In order to accomplish this, I have written a small bash script:

```
#!
iptables -F

iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP

iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 56988 -m state --state NEW -m recent --set --name ssh -rsource
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 56988 -m state --state NEW -m recent --update --seconds 60 --hitcount 8 --rttl --name ssh -j DROP
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 56988 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dports 80,443 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sports 80,443 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dports 80,443 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --sports 80,443 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dports 80,443 -m state --state NEW -m limit --limit 50/minute --limit-burst 200 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -m limit --limit 50/second --limit-burst 50 -j ACCEPT

/etc/init.d/iptables save
```

Though after running this, I am being blocked out through SSH. What am I doing wrong with this configuration? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have no rule to "allow connections on 56988". Everything for that port falls off your input chain and is rejected by the DROP policy. Could it be that you just forgot to change those 22's to 56988?

Comment: As an aside: the canonical way to go about iptables in RHEL/Centos is to save the rules in **/etc/sysconfig/iptables** rather than writing a script for it.

Comment: Yes Karma, you're right. While testing I have changed these values, should be 56988. Though that has been tested too.

Comment: Well, I still don't see a rule to accept connections on port 56988. Somthing like: iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 56988 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm glad to see you've clarified the issue with respect to port numbers.  Now, all I'm doing is formalising the comments by Karma Fusebox and Laurentiu Roescu, because they've identified the actual problem: you're specifying which ssh packets to drop, but never which ones to accept.  You need to insert a line as follows:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 56988 -m state --state NEW -m recent --set --name ssh -rsource
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 56988 -m state --state NEW -m recent --update --seconds 60 --hitcount 8 --rttl --name ssh -j DROP
###### new line is the next one #########
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 56988 -j ACCEPT
###### new line was the previous one ####
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 56988 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Do you see why?  Your INPUT chain has a bunch of logic about rate-limiting, and rejects any packets that exceed the rate limit - but it then never makes any provision for those NEW packets which **don't** fail the rate-limit test, so they pass through the entire chain and die on the policy (DROP).

I would have just upvoted vasco.debian's answer, but the **position** of this new line is important.  Because iptables works on a first-dispositive-match-wins basis, the new line must come **after** the rate-limiting lines; otherwise *all* NEW packets will match this new line, and never get tested against the rate-limiting line first.

Comment: Great answer MadHatter, thank you! +1 for the clear explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious problem is that you opened port 22, but put ssh listening on port 56988. This is what you need to change.

Comment: My fault, this was a problem due to a testversion. I have changed it accordingly. Though, still being locked out.

Answer (score 0):

Is `sshd` listening on port 56988? By default, SELinux prevents `sshd` from binding to non-standard port.

Comment: Yes, as posted in the first line of the question, I have changed /etc/ssh/sshd_config by editing the line `#Port 22` to `Port 56988`. After that a restart of the service ofcourse.

Comment: Anyway, you can investigate the problem this way: flush `iptables` counters, then take a look at `iptables` counters while trying to connect from remote host. Thus you can see what rule exactly are applied to SSH packets.

Answer (score 0):

Try following.

```
/sbin/iptable -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 56988 -j ACCEPT
```

This will insert rule at the top of INPUT chain